# Determinant of a symmetric, sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, sparse-matrices

I'm trying to calculate the determinant of the $q \times q$ matrix shown [here](http://www.mathematik.com/Hofstadter/index.html):

$$L(y)=\begin{bmatrix} V(1) & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & V(2) & 1  & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0& 1 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & 1 & V(q-1) & 1 \\
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & V(q) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $V(k) = 2 \cos(2 \pi k \frac{p}{q} )$, and $y = \frac{p}{q}$.

(Purpose: I want to calculate a Lyapunov exponent, in order to render [Hofstadter's Butterfly](http://www.mathematik.com/Hofstadter/index.html) using a GLSL shader.)

The matrix is symmetric and sparse, but is not positive definite, because the diagonals are not always positive.

My linear algebra is weak, but I'm trying to follow instructions, learning as I go. According to [wikipedia on computing determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Decomposition_methods), I can't use Cholesky because the matrix is not positive definite; so LU decomposition looks like the next best bet.

However there are [multiple algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Algorithms) for LU decomposition, and I'm starting to get lost in the weeds. I'm wondering if there is any particular shortcut that I can use because of the sparseness, and the highly constrained pattern of zeroes and ones in the matrix.

There is obviously a strong "algorithms" component to this question, so I debated whether to post it on cs.stackechange.com. However, at this point I think my question is more on the math side: What properties does the above matrix have that might make it easy prey for shortcuts?

If it helps, $q$ is likely to be in the range from 4 up to at least 50, and ideally even up to 1000.

## Update

If anyone is interested, the implementation of Hofstadter's Butterfly is [here](http://www.huttar.net/lars-kathy/misc/hofstadter-butterfly/hofstadter-butterfly.html). I had promised long ago to post it, so here it is. As for the algorithm, it's been a long time and I don't remember many details, but apparently I ported code from this [java applet](https://web.archive.org/web/20010528223855/http://wptx15.physik.uni-wuerzburg.de/TP3/source_java/hofstadter.java) from [Physics by Computer](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642468414). I can't say I really understand what it's doing, but it [doesn't look like](http://www.huttar.net/lars-kathy/misc/hofstadter-butterfly/hofstadter-butterfly.js) it's calculating the determinant of a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an appropriate multiple of row 2 to the last row so as to kill the $(q,1)$-th entry. Then add an appropriate multiple of row 3 to the last row kill the $(q,2)$-th entry. Continue in this manner, you can eliminate the entries on the last row one by one.

Suppose in the last but one step, the last row becomes $(0,0,\ldots,0,p,\ast,\ast)$ for some number $p$. Then, by subtracting $p$ times the $(q-1)$-th row from the last row, the last row is reduced to the form of $(0,0,\ldots,0,0,\alpha,\beta)$.

Now, *in theory*, if we further apply the analogous series of column additions to the last column of the matrix, we may also eliminate the first $q-2$ entries on the last column. However, as each column addition only affects the last column, all except the last entries of the last row are unaffected. Since the column operations here are merely transposed versions of the row operations, it follows that the last column must become $(0,0,\ldots,0,\alpha,\ast)^T$, where the $\alpha$ here is the same $\alpha$ that we have mentioned before. The bottom right entry is changed by the last column addition. So, it becomes $\beta-p\alpha$, where $\beta$ and $p$ are again the same ones that we have mentioned before.

Therefore, the result of the series of column operations is in fact completely determined by the previous result of the series of row additions. So, in practice, we don't really need to carry out the column operations. All we need is to determine $p,\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the last two steps of row additions, and $L(y)$ would be reduced to
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix} V(1) & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & V(2) & 1  & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0& 1 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & 1 & V(q-1) & \alpha \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \alpha & \beta-p\alpha
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
As only three entries of the last row are updated in each iteration, the total time complexity is $O(q)$. Also, as row/column additions do not change the determinant of a matrix, $M$ and $L(y)$ have the same determinants.

$M$ is tridiagonal. It is well-known that its determinant can be evaluated recursively in $O(q)$ operations: denote the determinant of the trailing $k\times k$ submatrix of $M$ by $D_k$ (so that $\det L(y)=\det M=\det D_q$); then by Laplace expansion, we have
\begin{align}
D_1&=\beta-p\alpha,\\
D_2&=V(q-1)(\beta-p\alpha) -\alpha^2,\\
D_k&=V(q+1-k)D_{k-1}-D_{k-2};\quad k\ge3.
\end{align}
So, in total, $\det L(y)$ can be evaluated in $O(q)$ operations.

Comment: This sounds very helpful. Sorry for the delay in responding ... somehow I didn't see a notification of the answer. Can you elaborate on "add an appropriate multiple of row 2 to the last row so as to kill the (q,1)-th entry"? I'm not sure what the (q-1)th entry means ... the entry in the (q-1)th column of the last row? And I don't know what it means to kill it... I would have thought that mean to make it zero, but that can't be, since no multiple of row 2 can change the (q-1)th entry in the any row, because row 2 has a zero there.

Comment: @LarsH The $(i,j)$-th entry means the entry at the $i$-th row and $j$-th column. So, the $(q,1)$-th is at the bottom left. To kill it means to make it zero. Subtract the **second** row from the last row, the $(q,1)$-th entry becomes zero and the last row becomes $(0,-V(2),-1,0,\ldots,0,1,V(q)$. Next, add $V(2)$ times the **third** row to the last row. So the $(q,2)$-th entry also vanishes and the last row becomes $(0,0,V(2)V(3)-1,V(2),0,\ldots,0,1,V(q)$. Continue in this manner, you can eliminate the entries on the last row one by one, until only two remain.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I kept misreading ($q$, 1)-th as ($q$-1)th. Thanks for the additional explanation.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how $M[1,q]$ was "killed," and how $M[q-1,q]$ became $\alpha$ instead of 1, and then I realized: In addition to adding multiples of various rows to the last row, we must also (implicitly) be adding the same multiples of corresponding columns to the last column. And this matters because it will affect the value of $\beta$. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Also, I don't quite follow "Now, by matrix congruence, the determinant of L(y) is equal to the determinant of M." Again, my linear algebra is weak, but according to Piziak & Odell's *Matrix Theory*, "Congruent matrices need not have ... the same determinant." (p. 439) Did you mean, "by matrix similarity"?

Comment: @LarsH I do mean matrix congruence, not matrix similarity. The determinant is preserved here because row/column additions correspond to multiplications of elementary matrices with determinant 1. So the determinant in this particular case is preserved by congruence.

Comment: OK. Am I understanding right about adding multiples of columns as well as of rows? (This comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709987/determinant-of-a-symmetric-sparse-matrix/1710063?noredirect=1#comment3504714_1710063)

Comment: @LarsH Yes, precisely.

Comment: Thanks for all the followup! I clicked "accept." I will try to remember to post a link here when I have the above implemented. Um... I also just saw that you had edited the answer. Will read that now.

Comment: Following your 3rd paragraph, I believe as you're adding multiples of columns, those are the columns that we've already modified, not the original column values, which is why you end up with $\beta - p\alpha$ in the corner, instead of $\beta - p$. (That's probably obvious to many people, but I didn't catch it at first. I'm thinking out loud so that if I'm thinking wrong, someone might correct me.)

Comment: I updated the equation for $D_2$ in the section about Laplace expansion, to take into account your edit regarding $\beta - p\alpha$. My edit is in the peer review queue at the moment.

Comment: @LarsH Thanks for catching that.

Comment: In fulfillment of an old promise: I've updated the question with a link to an implementation.